# Jenkins search bug (redirects to 404)

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins search box doesn't work correctly.

If I search for something like "test", I get redirected to /job/Test/ which produces a 404.
If I search for "testtt", I get the correct response that nothing was found.
If I search for some specific jobs, I get redirected to that job page correctly.

I suspect that the search somehow lists and redirects to old jobs that have been moved, renamed or deleted. I just don't know how to fix that.

We are using Jenkins 2.235.3 right now, but we had that problem much longer.

Comment: It is interesting that it goes to `/job/Test/` , when I do a search it actually goes to `/search/?q=Test`

Comment: @mdabdullah when I type in /search/?q=Test, I also get redirected to /job/Test/

Comment: I also just noticed, that our paths and names sometimes doesn't match. We have a folder with jobs called "AHT" and the path is /job/ONHT/ which might have or might not have been the previous name of the folder.

Comment: The "folder" essentially is just another plugin so maybe you need to upgrade your `Folder Plugin` and then do a reboot of the `master` in order for changes to take place. Coming to your original problem, there are different search options too which you can explore like the `OpenSearch` . 
Ref: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Search+Box#:~:text=Using%20Search%20Box,foo%22%20job%20build%20%2353.

Comment: Yes, we use the Folder Plugin, but we use already the newest version and the problem is much older than this upgrade.
And I need to fix this for all users. Installing a browser plugin isn't efficient.

Comment: Ok. I find it awkward that `test` should redirect to `Test` (case insensitive search). This sounds like an indexing issue and some cached data is still being referred to. It also sounds like a problem which does not go away when you do a restart of the server and the jenkins application. This seems unique to your instance, but wading through the XML files on the `master` may actually end up corrupting something else. Is this something you can try `https://plugins.jenkins.io/lucene-search/` , this plugin offers an opportunity to rebuild an index and the that will be baselined from thereon.

Comment: you are right. The change from test to Test is also wired.
I don't have access to the hosting sever and can't look for files therefore, but I will try the plugin you suggested, thx.

Comment: Please share your results and then we can mark this question closed. Also, if you do not have access to the `master` , you should talk to the person who is the `admin` as they will also have insight into this problem.

Comment: The OpenSearch plugin didn't fix the problem. It just added other search results to the list, but the dead links still appeared.
I have admin rights on the server, I just can't access the hosting machine.

Comment: Thats bad. There are some stale objects on your `jenkins host` there is a lot you can do via GUI, but I think all options have been exhausted. It's time to talk to the unix admin.